# WeTransfer iframe button open in new page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I use a WeTransfer Plus account and direct my users to the page with the link WeTransfer provides.

This is an `iframe`. I would like to open the page in a new window/tab but WeTransfer doesn't provide that option.

I tried adding `target="_blank"` to it but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

```
<iframe src="https://web.site/send/LANGUAGE/PROFILE_NAME" width="WIDTH" height="50" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

---- UPDATE -----

Soooooooo. WeTransfer came up with this answer:

> So it is something that's going to be implemented and I've now followed up with the tech department to make sure it does.
>   I'm really sorry that we don't have it just yet, though.

Can anyone provide me with a possibel solution/idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714630/clicking-on-iframe-open-new-tab-in-browser you could launch a new tab when there is click event on the iframe.

Comment: Well. I know I have to do something that isn't regular due to WeTransfer's limitations. But to create a invisible div is a little to much crap work to be honest. Thnx for the time and idea tho'